# trying to understand this recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I need to take a linked list and return a mirror version of it, here is an example

input: 1->2->3->4->5->null.

result: 1->2->3->4->5->5->4->3->2->1->NULL.

I have to visit each node once only

I managed to solve it but I really cant understand the solution so can anyone help me break down the mirror function?

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;

} node;


void PushEnd(node** headRef, int data)

{
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (!newnode)
        return;

    newnode->data = data;

    if (*headRef == NULL)
        {
            newnode->next = NULL;
            *headRef = newnode;
        }
    else
        {
            node* current = *headRef;
            node* prev;
            while (current->next)
                {
                    current = current->next;
                }
            current->next = newnode;
            newnode->next = NULL;
        }
}


void printList(node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    printf("%d ", head->data);

    printList(head->next);
}
node* mirror(node* head)
{
    node* new = NULL;
     
    if (head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    
    PushEnd(&new,head->data);
    
    new->next=mirror(head->next);
   PushEnd(&new, head->data); 
    return new;
}
void Test()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    
    int a[] = {10,50,19,54,30};
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) / sizeof(int)); i++)
        {
            PushEnd(&head, a[i]);
            
        }
    printList(head);
    printf("\n");
    node* new = mirror(head);
    printList(new);
}
int main()
{
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

using this call :  new->next=mirror(head->next);
how does it push the first element?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you manage to solve things, and are sure you have solved them, but you don't understand why, then I know a lot of companies that would be interested by your profile. Generally, software projects are cluttered with problems noone understands :-)

Comment: Even if I know too many developers of that kind... How could you pretend to have solved it (yourself) and you do not know how it works? Is "to solve" the new word for "to copy randomly found stuff and, wow, magically it works"? -- Anyway, insert lots of `printf()` calls in your code to follow the flow of control and to watch relevant values. This is the simple alternative to using a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first call of the function the pointer `new` is equal to NULL. Then the function  `PushEnd` is called.

```
PushEnd(&new,head->data);
```

So now the result list looks like (if to use data from your array)

```
| 10 | NULL |
     ^
     |
    new
```

Then the function calls recursively itself ( for example for the array element with the value 50)

```
new->next=mirror(head->next);
```

After exit from this call and due to the assignment to the pointer new->next in the statement above you will have

```
| 10 | ->50 | -> | 50 | ...| -> ... | ...| NULL|
     ^
     |
    new
```

Now the value 10 is appended to the tail of the list

```
PushEnd(&new, head->data);
```

and you will have

```
| 10 | ->50 | -> | 50 | ...| -> ... | ...| ->10 | -> | 10 | NULL |
     ^
     |
    new
```

This approach is inefficient due to the call of the function `PushEnd` because it needs to traverse the whole new built list to achieve its tail.

Comment: sorry for coming back late.
My instructor say that the mirror function traverse the original linked list multiple times
can you please elaborate
Thanks btw!